# It is not working, and Right place to implement onSaveInstanceStance()

Tags: android

I am trying to grasp the concept of life cycle call back methods of an activity and what happens inside them.
I am writing a small activity class which just displays a text. 
The Problem is that the activity starts to display and i get a dialog saying "unfortunately Activity Lifecycle and Coordination has stopped working"

1. Please tell me how to fix this.

   The code is as follows:-

   package com.practice.lifecycle_coordination;

   ```
   //import android.app.ActionBar;
   import android.app.Activity;
   //import android.os.Build;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   class MainActivity extends Activity{
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       }

       protected void onStart(){
           super.onStart();
       }

       protected void onResume(){
           super.onResume();
       }

       protected void onPause(){
           super.onPause();
       }

       protected void onStop(){
           super.onStop();
       }

       public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
       }

   }
   ```

LAYOUT FILE:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

STRINGS RESOURCE FILE:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Activity LifeCycle</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title">MAIN ACTIVITY</string>

</resources>
```

1. Is onSaveInstanceState() implemented at the right place? In case I want to save some additional data into the bundle, is this the right place to implement it?

I know that I don't need to write any life cycle call back methods except onCreate(). But I just wanted to check.

Comment: We need the stack trace from logcat to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write `onCreate()` actually.  The only life cycle methods you have to write are ones in which you need to override and implement your own code within.  `onCreate()` is overwritten in virtually every `Activity`, however, because you typically are going to want to use this point in the life cycle to initialize variables etc.

---

As for `Is onSaveInstanceState() implemented at the right place?`

Yes.  The order within your `Activity` in which your life cycle methods occur doesn't matter in the slightest.  As long as you're in the right activity, you're fine.  These methods are called automatically as your activity goes through those life cycle stages.

---

As for what's actually wrong with the current code?  We'll need a lot more information.  Your logcat will give you some information on what actually caused the crash.  Post that, and your problem can be better diagnosed.